# ZMQ error : address already in use, depending on user

Tags: c++, zeromq

I use ZMQ in a C++ program.

The program compiles successfully, but throws an exception when launched with my **web_admin** user :

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'zmq::error_t'
what():  Address already in use
```

What I really don't understand, is that if I launch the program as root, no error is raised.

The executable has the following permissions :

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 web_admin root       487347 févr. 27 00:28 isochrones
```

Also, I have checked using the command :

```
netstat -ltnp
```

that the corresponding port is **not** in use.

Any idea why launching the program with web_admin fails, but succeeds with root ?

Comment: Which port are you trying to listen to? Please note that ports below 1024 (also known as well-known ports) can only be listened by root users

Comment: I did various tries between 5555-5566

Comment: Create a minimal test program, just a `main()` using zeromq with the bind. See if that has the same issue. Maybe there is some other socket connection (inproc/ipc etc) going on in the program. Either way you will get more help if you can post a minimal example of the issue.

Comment: Impossible to say without looking at the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is closed : I just reinstalled everything from scratch, restarted the server and it worked.